# Autocomplete function with HTML, CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a selection to see which country I'm hovering over. I have been trying, but can't seem to get it working.

```js
// Sample list of autocomplete options
var countries = [
  "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia"
];

// Get references to the input field and the dropdown list
var input = document.getElementById("country-name");
var autocompleteList = document.getElementById("suggestion-list");

// Event listener for input field
input.addEventListener("input", function() {
  var inputValue = input.value;
  autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';

  // Filter and display matching items
  countries.forEach(function(country) {
    if (country.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
      var item = document.createElement("li");
      item.textContent = country;
      item.addEventListener("click", function() {
        input.value = country;
        autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';
      });
      item.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        item.classList.add("active"); // Add the "active" class on hover
      });
      item.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
        item.classList.remove("active"); // Remove the "active" class when not hovering
      });
      autocompleteList.appendChild(item);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
/* Styles for the autocomplete container */

.autocomplete {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


/* Styles for the input field */

input[type="text"] {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  /* Set initial border to transparent */
  transition: border 0.3s;
  /* Add a transition for a smooth effect */
}


/* Add border only when the input is not empty */

input[type="text"]:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  /* Show border when not empty */
}


/* Styles for the autocomplete dropdown */

.autocomplete-items {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 150px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Remove the list icon */
  width: 200px;
  /* Match the width of the input field */
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  /* Set initial border to transparent */
}


/* Styles for each autocomplete item */

.autocomplete-item {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* Highlight the selected item */

.autocomplete-item:hover {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}


/* Highlight the selected item */

.autocomplete-item.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
  /* Customize the highlight color */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Story Fetcher</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/autocomplete.css">
  <!-- Include the new CSS file for autocomplete -->
  <script type="module" src="autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script src="country.js"></script>
  <!-- Include your country.js script here -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Select a country</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="get-container">
        <input type="text" id="country-name" placeholder="Enter a country" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="suggestion-list" class="autocomplete-items"></div>
        <button id="get" type="button">Get Country</button>
        <div id="error-message"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="story-container">
        <div id="generated-text"></div>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

I'm pretty sure it's an easy fix, but I just can't see how to implement this highlighting function, or what to call it. How can I fix this?

Comment: if I understand correctly your struggle, the way to style the autocomplete items when the mouse is hovering them, just requires you to add a css rule like this `.autocomplete-items li:hover{background: yellow;}` .. and just forget about the js event listener `mouseover` and `mouseout`

Comment: So where in the CSS would this go?

Comment: anywhere as long as it's a `<style>` tag. It's just a css rule like the others ([:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)) .. the selector using the `:hover` pseudo-class will match the element only when the mouse is hovering and that style will be applied

Comment: you were using this `.autocomplete-item:hover` in your rules.. but you never added the `autocomplete-item` class to the newly created elements so that rule was never going to match. The whole js thing dealing with the mouse event is not required anymore if you just rely on that css feature as long as you just need to style single items when mouse hovering. Please get rid of it.. I see it used also in the answer given

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an autocomplete function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77278030/adding-an-autocomplete-function)

Comment: "can't seem to get it working" - what exactly does that mean? Is this a JS problem, an HTML problem, or a CSS problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATES:**

- I have updated some of the code in JS. I am using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.
- You need to add `item.classList.add("autocomplete-item");` line which adds a class `autocomplete-item`.
- Use the `background-color` property on your `autocomplete-items` to make it appear above the textbox. I updated the code as per your comment.
- I have changed the position of `autocomplete-items` to absolute to ensure proper positioning of the list items with respect to input field.

Below is the code implementation for the same:

```js
// Sample list of autocomplete options
var countries = [
    "Afghanistan", "Albania", "Algeria", "Andorra", "Angola", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia"
];

// Get references to the input field and the dropdown list
var input = document.getElementById("country-name");
var autocompleteList = document.getElementById("suggestion-list");

// Event listener for input field
input.addEventListener("input", function () {
    var inputValue = input.value;
    autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';

    // Filter and display matching items
    countries.forEach(function (country) {
        if (country.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            var item = document.createElement("li");
            item.textContent = country;
            item.classList.add("autocomplete-item"); // Add the "autocomplete-item" class
            item.addEventListener("click", function () {
                input.value = country;
                autocompleteList.innerHTML = '';
            });
            item.addEventListener("mouseenter", function () {
                item.classList.add("active"); // Add the "active" class on hover
            });
            item.addEventListener("mouseleave", function () {
                item.classList.remove("active"); // Remove the "active" class when not hovering
            });
            autocompleteList.appendChild(item);
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/* Styles for the autocomplete container */
.autocomplete {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Styles for the input field */
input[type="text"] {
    width: 200px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid transparent; /* Set initial border to transparent */
    transition: border 0.3s; /* Add a transition for a smooth effect */
}

/* Add border only when the input is not empty */
input[type="text"]:not(:placeholder-shown) {
    border: 1px solid #ccc; /* Show border when not empty */
}

/* Styles for the autocomplete dropdown */
.autocomplete-items {
    position: absolute; /* Changed position to absolute */
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    list-style-type: none; /* Remove the list icon */
    width: 200px; /* Match the width of the input field */
    border: 1px solid transparent; /* Set initial border to transparent */
    background-color: #fff; /* Add a background color to the dropdown list as per your comment */
}

/* Styles for each autocomplete item */
.autocomplete-item {
    padding: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Highlight the selected item */
.autocomplete-item:hover {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

/* Highlight the selected item */
.autocomplete-item.active {
    background-color: #ccc; /* Customize the highlight color */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Story Fetcher</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/index.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/autocomplete.css">
  <!-- Include the new CSS file for autocomplete -->
  <script type="module" src="autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script src="country.js"></script>
  <!-- Include your country.js script here -->
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Select a country</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="content-wrapper">
      <div id="get-container">
        <input type="text" id="country-name" placeholder="Enter a country" autocomplete="off">
        <div id="suggestion-list" class="autocomplete-items"></div>
        <button id="get" type="button">Get Country</button>
        <div id="error-message"></div>
      </div>
      <div id="story-container">
        <div id="generated-text"></div>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```